# Getting Error while deploying angular application in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am getting an Error while deploying angular application in firebase
here is the error stack

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '/Users/***/Desktop/myWebsite/SSR/***/functions/dist/***/server'
    Require stack:
    - /Users/***/Desktop/myWebsite/SSR/***/functions/lib/index.js
    - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js
    
    Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

can someone help me why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps one by one:

- **ng build --prod**
  //this builds your files (js,json,modules,routings) in one complex file name dist/"your file name"
- **npm install -g firebase-tools**
  //npm is node package manager it works if you have your node installed and this command is used for installing tools related to firebase
  -**firebase login**
  //the firebase email  login will be successful in which you created your database
- **firebase init**
  //initialises your project(series of questions will appear as hosting option ,configuration of all files in one index.html(no),the path (dist/your-proj-name),ooverwritting html file,etc)
- **firebase deploy**